# Create a Jar From a Spring Boot Console App That Requires Injection From Custom Arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, installation

I am making an app that requires an argument from the command line using Spring Boot, the passed argument then will be passed on to a field as follow:

```
@Value("#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse('${param.date}')}")
private Date date;
```

However, when I tried to create the Jar file using the command `mvnw package`, the following error is shown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'param.date' in value "#{new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse('${param.date}')}"
```

How can I tell the compiler that the aforementioned field is from an argument? And, if the jar is made then, how do I inject the field when running the jar using command line arguments?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce it. Try this:

```sh
java -jar [target].jar --param.date=01-11-2021
```

If tests failing, try [`@SpringBootTest(args = "--param.date=01-11-2021")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.using-application-arguments).

([sample code](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so69796060))

Refs:

- [7.2.1. Accessing Command Line Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.command-line-args)

> By default, `SpringApplication` converts any command line option arguments (that is, arguments starting with `--`, such as `--server.port=9000`) to a `property` and adds them to the Spring `Environment`.

- [7.26.3. Testing Spring Boot Applications > Using Application Arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.using-application-arguments)

Comment: You haven't mentioned how to make the jar first. The solution you gave can only be tried when the jar is already created.

Comment: When that error occurs? Please paste log without omission. Args are not required on `package` phase.

Answer (score 0):

The command `mvnw package` was failed because of the spring unit test. I just had to skip the unit test using the `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` parameter. So, the complete command would be `mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`. As for on how to run the .jar with the parameters once the jar is created, can be seen in DEWA Kazuyuki - 出羽和之
's answer.